# execute command only if existing record for a model is being updated

Tags: django

I have this modesl.py below. I need to execute something only when the record is being updated and not created for Target model(e.g. when I update Target.Name via admin). So far the below code executes only when I create new Target record, not update existing one. Spent one day on this...

def create_badge(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

```
if not created:
   #execute stuff here if record being UPDATED
   os.system('touch /tmp/mark')
   pass
else:
    os.system('touch /tmp/mark2')
```

class Target(models.Model):

```
Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
UID = models.CharField(max_length=15)
SSH = models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

signals.post_save.connect(create_badge, sender=Target)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom `save()` method on the model. Then you can take advantage of the fact that, when the instance is being modified, it will already have a `id`, but if it's being created it won't yet (because the `id` is assigned when it's saved for the first time). So set your function to be called only if there's already a `id`. For example:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self):
        if self.id:
            do_something_here()
        super(ModelName, self).save()
```

Comment: It seems that signals dont work when doing bulk update. I have the update triggered on multiple items via custom admin action. Basically I wanted to trigger a command after post_save after bulk update via admin...